# Control panel submenus not expanding and 503 service unavailable error

Tags: control-panel, javascript, jquery, ajax

Sometimes the top submenus are not showing . Same time when we check the browser console we can see '503 Service unavailable' .

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="secure_access.php?S=0c587174500c93563f4efd82b4275a3984fb1c87&amp;D=cp&amp;C=javascript&amp;M=combo_load&amp;ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&amp;plugin=ee_focus,ee_interact.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&amp;file=cp/global_start&amp;effect=core&amp;v=1359470773"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="secure_access.php?S=0c587174500c93563f4efd82b4275a3984fb1c87&amp;D=cp&amp;C=javascript&amp;M=combo_load&amp;file=cp/global_end&amp;v=1359470108"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

GET secure_access.php?S=0c587174500c93563f4efd82b4275a398…,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&file=cp/global_start&effect=core&v=1359470773 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

This submenu issue is not happening always. At the same time, one admin user sees the issue, but another admin user don't have this issue.

Can anyone advise whats the issue and how to be sorted. I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue was  that the javascript files that makes the menu working didn't get downloaded from server. This happened because there was an issue on server and hence we were shown the '503 service unavailable' error.

The '503 service unavailable' was due to varnish and apache disagreeing with the size of gzipped content. When this issue got fixed on server the javascript resource downloaded properly and the submenu started working.